# AD Query “the remote server does not exist or is unavailable”

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

What a great idea.  I redid the script with your suggestion.   It however has another problem. The new script only returns the last computer in the computer OU. How do you correctly pass each instance from the Dictionary to the If statement?

```
 dim strComputer, objFileToWrite, objWMIService

 If Reachable(QueryAD) Then

Set objFileToWrite =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("\\cheeng.net\winc\IT\NuanceKey.txt",8,true)

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & QueryAD & "\root\cimv2")
Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each objComputer in colComputer
    objFileToWrite.Write VBNewLine & "User Name = " & objComputer.UserName _
        & VBNewLine & "Computer Name = " & objComputer.Name
Next  
WScript.Echo  QueryAD & " Computer is Reachable!"
Else 
WScript.Echo QueryAD & "Computer is Unreachable!"
 End If



Function QueryAD

Dim objDictionary, strItem, colItems, i, s
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=WINC,DC=cheeng,DC=net")
objOU.Filter = Array("Computer")

For Each objComputer in objOU    ' Add Workstations to Dictionary
    objDictionary.Add a, objComputer.CN
    a = a + 1 
colItems = objDictionary.Items  ' Get the workstations.

for i = 0 to objDictionary.count -1 ' Iterate the array.
    s = colItems(i) ' Create return string.

next
QueryAD = s

Next
End Function 


Function Reachable(strComputer) 'Test Connectivty to computer
Dim wmiQuery, objWMIService, objStatus

' Define the WMI query
wmiQuery = "Select * From Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & strComputer & "'"

' Run the WMI query
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery(wmiQuery)

' Translate the query results to either True or False
For Each objStatus in objWMIService
If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) Or objStatus.Statuscode<>0 Then
    Reachable = False 'if computer is unreachable, return false
Else
    Reachable = True 'if computer is reachable, return true
End If
Next

Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you connect to the remote computer, you need to ping it to see if it's online. Here's a function that does that.

```
Function Reachable(strComputer) 'Test Connectivty to computer
Dim wmiQuery, objWMIService, objPing, objStatus
wmiQuery = "Select * From Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & strComputer & "'"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objPing = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)
For Each objStatus in objPing
    If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) Or objStatus.Statuscode<>0 Then
        Reachable = False 'if computer is unreachable, return false
    Else
        Reachable = True 'if computer is reachable, return true
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Then to use this function you can do a

```
If Reachable("computername") Then
    Set objWMIService = GetObject...etc
```

**Edit:**

You'll want to add the reachable function inside your For loop and send one computer at a time to the function.

You also might want to query AD for only computers that are active. For example:

```
Set objFileToWrite =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("\\cheeng.net\winc\IT\NuanceKey.txt",8,true)

arrComps = QueryAD

For Each strComputer in arrComps

If Reachable(strComputer) Then 
    Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Computer is Reachable!"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
    For Each objComputer in colComputer
        objFileToWrite.Write VBNewLine & "User Name = " & objComputer.UserName _
        & VBNewLine & "Computer Name = " & objComputer.Name
        'You could also use strComputer here instead of objComputer.Name
Else 'If not reachable
    Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Computer is Unreachable!"
End If 'End Reachable If

Next  'Loop to next computer

Function QueryAD
    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    Dim objDictionary, colItems, strComputer
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDomain = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    Set objCOmmand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = _
        "Select Name from 'LDAP://" & strDomain & "' " _
        & "Where objectClass='computer' and userAccountControl <> 4098 and userAccountControl <> 4130"
    'This will get all computers except disabled computers from AD
    objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
    objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 
    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
    objRecordSet.MoveFirst

    Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
        strComputer = objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value
        objDictionary.Add strComputer,strComputer
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
    objRecordSet.Close
    QueryAD = objDictionary.Items
End Function 

Function Reachable(strComputer) 'Test Connectivty to computer
    'keep the same as you had it
End Function
```

Comment: What a great idea.  I redid the script with your suggestion.   It however has another problem. The new script only returns the last computer in the computer OU. How do you correctly pass each instance from the Dictionary to the If statement?

Comment: In your function you were setting s = colItems(i) which will reset s at each loop, and at the last loop s will = the last item. If you want to return an array, just set the array = objDictionary.Items.

I updated the code to help you out.

Comment: You have been very helpful. Thanks. I am just learning how to do this.  The company I work at is a child company which has 3 sisters. There are thousands of workstations that I do not care about in active directory. Is there any way to specify a specific folder in this new function?

Comment: `strOU = "OU=Computers,OU=WINC,"`
`"Select Name from 'LDAP://" & strOU & strDomain & "'...`